# Advanced SQL Select and update items from the same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has the rows `item_id` (unique key), `base_id`, `step_id`, and `active`.

What i need to do is update everything in that table, that matches `base_id` where `step_id` = 1 and `active` = 0 to `active` = 1 that doesn't have an entry in the same table with the same `base_id` and `step_id` = 2 and `active` = 1.

```
----------------------------------------
| item_id | base_id | step_id | active |  
| 1       | 1       | 1       | 0      |
| 2       | 1       | 2       | 1      |
| 3       | 2       | 1       | 0      |
| 4       | 3       | 1       | 0      |
| 5       | 3       | 1       | 0      |
----------------------------------------
```

This would return make item 3, 4, and 5 update to have `active` = 1

If that makes sense.  Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the table so that the matching values have `active` set to `1` we can take the [solution by juergen d](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32279401/1175077) and turn it into an update statement.

As MySQL has some issues with updating a table that it is referencing in a subquery we insert an extra level of nesting which forces the creation of a temporary result and allows the update:

```
update table1 t
set t.active = 1
where base_id in (
  select base_id from (
    select base_id
    from table1
    group by base_id
    having sum(step_id = 1 and active = 0) > 0
       and sum(step_id = 2 and active = 1) = 0
  ) a 
);
```

This would set `active = 1` for `item_id` `3, 4 and 5`

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2586b/1)

Answer (score 3):

```
select item_id 
from your_table
where base_id in
(
  select base_id
  from your_table
  group by base_id
  having sum(step_id = 1 and active = 0) > 0
     and sum(step_id = 2 and active = 1) = 0
)
```

What does the inner select do?
It groups the records by  `base_id` and takes only those having at least 1 record with `step_id = 1 and active` and zero records with `step_id = 2 and active = 1`.

`sum()` counts how many times the inner condition is true.

Comment: I edited the first post to give you an idea of what the expected results would be.

Comment: And doesn't that give your the desired result?

Comment: I've never used sum before, can you elaborate on how that would accomplish it?

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this with a simple `in` or `exists`:

```
select t.*
from table t
where step_id = 1 and active = 0 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where t2.base_id = t.base_id and t2.step_id = 2 and t2.active = 1
                 );
```

This seems like a direct translation of your description.